# Is the symbol ! used in mathematical writing to express something absurd?

Tags: notation

I remember that the exclamation mark ( ! ) was used while writing math to express a contradiction or reduction to absurd or something like that. But it seems that I do not remember well because doing some research I could not find this use. Just the well known:

- Factorial (Number Theory)
- Negation (Logic)
- Uniqueness of existence in conjuction with the symbol $\exists$ (Set Theory)

I have a "false memory" or something like that? or indeed the symbol is !! ?

What is used to write that a statement is absurd/contradicition?

Comment: For a contradiction I would use $\Rightarrow \Leftarrow$...

Comment: I often see $\perp$ or ↯ (the last one is more for blackboards). My personal habit is to write down "Contradiction" since there is no standard notation.

Comment: In logic the symbol "!" is used for [Uniqueness quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_quantification): $(\exists !)$.

Comment: For a contradiction, the [Falsum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_(logic)) symbol: $\bot$ is used.

Comment: @nicomezi I see... hmmm maybe all this time I was granted ↯ as a exclamation mark...

Comment: [Negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation) is usually $\lnot$ or $\sim$.

Comment: Yep, also overline. Negation $!$ is used in programming languages, not maths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refer to contradiction sometimes the symbol $$\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$$ however usually the word contradiction itself is used. But there is no symbol in mathematics for something absurd.

As you have rightly noted ! is used for factorial, negation and set theory. There you have it. If you want some more you might want to check out wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

As @MauroALLEGRANZA noted, a contradiction is often denoted $\bot$ (`\bot`), especially in model theory. Similarly, a tautology is $\top$ (`\top`). Thus all propositions $p$ satisfy $(\bot\implies p)\land(p\implies\top)$.